# About create private library with cocoapods

Tags: xcode, git, cocoapods

When I created my private library with cocoapods, I completed the local private spec and the corresponding local demo, and also uploaded the local demo to the remote git repository, and push tag '0.1.0'.

The verification of the pod is also smooth (pod spec lint).

```
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  note: Using new build system
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Planning build
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Constructing build description
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  warning: Skipping code signing because the target does not have an Info.plist file and one is not being generated automatically. (in target 'App' from project 'App')

Analyzed 1 podspec.

myBaseDemo.podspec passed validation.
```

But finally when I pushed the spec, reported a git mistake. I was confused about it.

```
 -> myBaseDemo (0.1.0)
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  note: Using new build system
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Planning build
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Constructing build description
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  warning: Skipping code signing because the target does not have an Info.plist file and one is not being generated automatically. (in target 'App' from project 'App')

Updating the `myBaseSpecs' repo

[!] /usr/bin/git -C /Users/fenglu/.cocoapods/repos/myBaseSpecs pull

Your configuration specifies to merge with the ref 'refs/heads/master'
from the remote, but no such ref was fetched.
```

Comment: Well, I had solved it by adding a file in the remote repository of podspec.